# What word means "shows emotion while acting" in a good way?

Tags: single-word-requests

I wanted to use "emote" to praise an actor. But when I looked it up, emote has one positive definition while all others are negative. Synonyms include "overacted" "ham it up" "exaggerate" "overact" etc. What word can I use that means "this actor conveys emotion while acting" or "this actor can convey strong emotions while acting" in a good way? For example, "This actor _____ while acting".

Comment: I didn't think emote had a positive or negative connotation. Care to link where you got those definitions from?

Comment: From the help center, for single-word-requests: "show users how this single word fits in a sentence" and "Questions that show no research are likely to be closed." Please provide a sentence with a blank where the word you want would go. Your question does show research: it looks as if [wordhippo](http://wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/emote.html) might've been your source for the synonyms, so it's also a good idea to link that source.

Comment: "show users how this single word fits in a sentence" I don't know what word to use. "this actor conveys emotion while acting" or "this actor can convey strong emotions while acting" isn't enough?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Keeleon, here you go: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/emote

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/emote

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/emote

Comment: I suppose what the help center refers to is a sentence with underscores or something like that: "this actor _____ while acting". The idea is to supply a notion of how you will use the word in a real sentence, rather than just supplying a description. In your case, it's not clear whether you want a word for "conveys emotion", "conveys strong emotion", "conveys emotion while acting", or "this actor conveys emotion while acting".

Comment: @Pep thanks for the links! I'll be sure to keep this in mind whenever I hear the word emote used. Maybe that review of my high school play _was_ sarcastic after all!

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple. I think you need to add an adverb to the brief phrase you used in your question; e. g.,

"This actor ***brilliantly*** conveys emotion."

(Or use any other adverb that accurately conveys the spirit of what you perceive in his or her work.)

Comment: You could say *he* or *she

Comment: @the_prole- What? :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Ingenious**

Synonyms from wiktionary:

> inventive, creative, imaginative, original, innovative, pioneering, resourceful, enterprising, inspired;
>
> clever, intelligent, smart, brilliant, masterly, talented, gifted, skillful;
>
> astute, sharp-witted, quick-witted, shrewd;
>
> elaborate, sophisticated.